# Add sample data to create() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How would a programmer add sample data to a Person class so it pre-populates the fields on the **view**?

Here is what I'm thinking but it doesn't work:

```
public class Person
{
  private Boolean prepopulate = false;

  public Person() { if (prepopulate) { Person(prepopulate); }}
  public Person(Boolean prepopulate)
  {
     if (prepopulate)
     {
         this.prepopulate = prepopulate;
         SampleData.Fill(ref this);
     }
  }

  int Id {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}
}
```

My create statement might look like this:

```
    //
    // GET: /Person/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Person person = new Person(prepopulate=true);
        return View(person);
    }
```

The fill would do something like this reference: [link](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/aspnet-45-preview-using-model-0).

Comment: Use a constructor in your model class.  Google it.

Comment: I have two constructor defined in the Person model.  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do to fix your problem, whenever a new entity is created it will automatically give it the properties inside the public Person() constructor.  I would highly recommend reading up on the constructors and how they work so you understand it better and understand why it works.

```
public class Person
{
  int Id {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}

  public Person()
  {
      Name = "Sample";
  }
}
```

Comment: I got it to work.  I'm using a static method b/c I like to use the Person.FieldName = "some sample data" syntax.  And for sub object Person.SubObject.FieldName syntax.  And if SubObject doesn't exist I use the Person.SubObject = new SubObject(); first then use the correct syntax.